# Accessing the full url, including hostname with jstl

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

```
<c:url var="myUrl" value="/MyPath/${MyID}"/>
```

which I then use later (to enable users to copy links) :

```
<input size="35" disabled value="${myUrl}" />
```

and it shows

```
/my-app-name/MyPath/23
```

however I want it to be

```
http://myHost/my-app-name/MyPath/23
```

I can prepend the string sure, but wanted a way to actively get the correct hostname ... ?

Comment: Sidenote: Remember that actively getting the hostname will give you the hostname that was used to reach your server. If it's an app behind a reverseProxy (by example an Apache rerouting request to your app-server) you will not have the hostname the user sees.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to prepare it yourself based on [`HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) and a little help of [JSTL functions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html):

```html
<c:set var="req" value="${pageContext.request}" />
<c:set var="baseURL" value="${fn:replace(req.requestURL, fn:substring(req.requestURI, 1, fn:length(req.requestURI)), req.contextPath)}" />
...
<c:url var="myUrl" value="${baseURL}/${MyID}"/>
```

Comment: that was quick, thnx, will give it a shot.

Comment: on tomcat 7.0.52, I had to change the start of the substring from 1 to 0 : `fn:substring(req.requestURI, 0, fn:length(req.requestURI)), etc.`

Comment: even better, on tomcat 7.0.52, simplified baseURL works for me: `<c:set var="baseURL" value="${fn:replace(req.requestURL, req.requestURI, req.contextPath)}" />`

Comment: @cthiebaud: this fails if webapp is deployed to context root and the request URI is "/". This also fails if the request URL contains -by coincidence- repeated parts of request URI. You'd really better substring off the exact part by index.

Answer (score 7):

HttpServletRequest object has all the details:

- `getProtocol`
- `getServerName`
- `getContextPath`

so I think you can use:

```
${request.protocol} :// ${request.serverName} ${request.contextPath} /etc
```

to build what you want.

Comment: You would only end up in a clumsy if-else logic flow in order to hide the port whenever it's already the default port for the given protocol. It's easier to build based on `getRequestURL()`. Also, the `getServerName()` is manipulatable by the client through the `Host` request header, I wouldn't rely on this.

Comment: Ok. I didn't think about hiding the port. I didn't go the getRequestURL way because the OP wanted to change the URL. One question. I didn't understood the servername manipulation. Is it that if the client send a Host:www.other.com that will get into our built URL?

Comment: got it working with ${pageContext.request.serverName}

Comment: What if I whant to get only the "page name", example: if i have http://localhost:8080/ticket/pages/cadastro.jsf then I need to check is "this" page is equal to "cadastro.jsf" (JSF/Primefaces) ?